# How to reduce number of memcache lookups?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, memcached, jinja2

I've managed to get rid of all the datastore queries for a website but according to appstats there are still 58 memcache lookups that I think can be reduced to 9 or less. SInce there is an iteration over 50 items and I believe that the iteration lookup that is done for every element can be done just one outside the loop for all the 50 elements, if the object is not too big which it probably isn't. And/or some more advanced model that can cache everything before rendering since there are 8 memcache lookups befor erendering and 50 after rendering i nthe template:

```
    {% for scored_document in results %}        
    <div class="item">
        <abbr class="date dtstart value item_age" title="2013-05-07T12:48:07+0000">
             {{scored_document.fields.10.value|format_date_human(locale='en')}}<br>{% if scored_document.fields.17 and scored_document.fields.18 %}    
{{scored_document.fields.17.value|displaytime(minutes =scored_document.fields.18.value )}}{% endif %}
        </abbr>    
      {% set testing = scored_document.fields.8.value|displayimg %}
        {% if testing and testing != 'False' %}
        <a lang="" class="item_img" tabindex="1" href="/vi/{{scored_document.fields.8.value|int|safe}}.html">    
                <img src="{{ testing }}" title="{{scored_document.fields.0.value|safe}}" alt="{{scored_document.fields.0.value|safe}}">    
        </a>    
        {% else %}
        <a lang="" class="item_img" tabindex="1" href="/vi/{{scored_document.fields.8.value|int|safe}}.html">
            &nbsp;
        </a>
        {% endif %}
```

The above code calls the filter function which uses memcache:

```
def displayimg(ad_id):
    from main import Ad
    uri2view = memcache.get('uri2view'+ad_id)
    if uri2view is None:
      ad = Ad.get_by_id(long(ad_id))
      memcache.add(ad_id, ad, 36000)
      uri2view = ad.uri2view()
      if uri2view is None:
          uri2view = False
      memcache.add('uri2view'+ad_id, uri2view, 36000)
    return str(uri2view)
```

The function uri2view is

```
def uri2view(self):
    data = memcache.get('img-serv-url'+str(self.key().id()))
    if data is not None:
        return data
    else:
        if self.matched_images.get():
          data = images.get_serving_url(self.matched_images.get().primary_image.key()  ,80)
        else:
          data = False
        memcache.add('img-serv-url'+str(self.key().id()), data, 36000)
        return data
```

The result in appstats is 58 memcache lookups, 8 on the backend plus 50 in the loop since the for loop was 50 times.

```
HTTP 200 real=1056ms api=0ms overhead=11ms (58 RPCs, cost=0, billed_ops=[])
memcache.Get    58
```

Now I suppose that it can be done with just one memcache lookup for the whole loop but how? I should be able to initiate a larger variable for all the items outside the loop, right? And I should also be able to do the 8 lookups on the backend with just one lookup and in the end combine these two to just 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to:

- add a layer of appcache. Keep in mind the appcache will take space in instance memory https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_App_caching
- if the results variable is always same, you can store all values you need in a single key, keep in mind there is memcache 1mb limit per entry.

Even though not reducing number of memcache calls, you can do the displayimg processing in batch (accept a list instead of single element), this way you save the amount of roundtrip for the API calls to datastore/memcache.